# Warning: React component classes must extend React.Component when using ScalaJS

Tags: reactjs, scala.js

I upgraded react to 0.14-rc1 from 0.14 beta3 , now i am seeing warnings

> Warning: $c_Hello$Component(...): React component classes must extend
>   React.Component.

but my component extending React.Component

```
object Hello {
  @ScalaJSDefined
  class Component extends ReactComponent[Unit, Unit] {
    def render() = React.createElement("div",null,"hello")
  }
}
```

no warnings in 0.14 beta3.

i think logic here is not correct ? : 
https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/b01af40ae64823fb963a8fa6ced3c42ae09fad55/src/renderers/shared/reconciler/ReactCompositeComponent.js#L170

in debug mode `inst instanceof Component` is true

Comment: The logic there is correct - `warning` warns when the first argument is `false`. So inverting the `instanceof` gives us what we want.

What is `ReactComponent` in your code? Is it `React.Component`?

Or is this something going differently in the transpilation from Scala to JS?l

Comment: its React.Component from reactjs ,i am just using alias for convenience in my code base .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like this is a scala-js bug where the .isReactClass flag doesn't get copied over. I've filed an issue there:[Static class properties should be inherited](https://github.com/scala-js/scala-js/issues/1900)

It looks like your code might also work if you change your sbt settings to use

```
scalaJSOutputMode := org.scalajs.core.tools.javascript.OutputMode.ECMAScript6
```

and then it will use native ES6 classes. But [the blog post in which it was introduced](http://www.scala-js.org/news/2015/05/12/announcing-scalajs-0.6.3/) suggests it's not ready for production use.